# Virar elementos collapse

Tags: css, angular

Tenho um elemento que eu quero virar ele conforme clica nele, este elemento é um collapse:

```
<td><a class="fa fa-chevron-down iconedetalhes" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{i}}" aria-expanded="false"  aria-hidden="true"></a>

   <p class="collapse" id="collapse{{i}}">
         teste
   </p>
```

Minha classe:

```
.iconedetalhes:focus{
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition-duration: 0.7s!important;
}
```

Porém dessa maneira eu tenho dois problemas:

O primeiro é que depois que clico no elemento ele vira, mas depois ele não desvira quando clico novamente.

Comment: Isso talvez seja pq vc está fazendo um "add class" quando na verdade deveria ser um "toggle class" isso se for com JS... Se for com CSS vc precisa usar um checkbox escondido para trocar a classe do irmão quando estiver checked ou uncheckd.... Não entendo bem o :focus pois assim que vc tirar o focos clicando em outro lugar qualquer ele tira a classe ...

Comment: Tentei mas quando clico na label ela nao checka a combobox. só quando clico na check ela vira o conteudo:

<input type="checkbox" id="hacky-input">
              <label for="hacky-input">          
                <a class="fa fa-chevron-down iconedetalhes crossRotate" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse{{i}}" aria-expanded="false"  aria-hidden="true"></a>
              </label>
                  <p class="collapse" id="collapse{{i}}">
                    teste
                  </p>

Comment: Da uma estudada nesse exemplo. Pelo seu CSS e pela estrutura do seu HTML as coisas estão bem esquisitas rss. Olha um exemplo aqui: https://codepen.io/origamid/pen/oeYQpK se ainda ficar com dúvida, me fala que eu monto um exemplo ainda mais simples pra vc com os detalhes de como montar esse tipo de "componente" ok

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método Toogle do JQuery para fazer a alternância entre classe e pseudo-classe baseada no evento de clique.

### JQuery

```js
 $('.rotacao').on('click', function(){ // exercido o evento de clique sobre a classe rotacao
      $(this).toggleClass('active'); // a classe rotação é alternada para a pseudo-classe rotacao:active
    });
```

```css
.rotacao{
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
      -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
      -o-transition-duration: 1s;
      transition-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
      -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
      -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
      transition-property: transform;
      outline: none;
}

    .rotacao:active {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
      transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title> Rotação </title>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI86p.png" width="20%" class="rotacao">
</body>
</html>
```

Para obter ações diferentes com o mouse podem ser usadas outras pseudo-classes como *hover*. Para seu caso, clicar(girar) e ao clicar novamente (retornar a posição normal), recomendo usar outra classe para alternância.

Comment: nao é recomendado usar jquery em conjunto com angular